# ejs issues loading htmlWebpackPlugin (is not defined)

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have what I believe is an ejs issue, and having cloned a github repo and not really used ejs before I'm having some issues. Strangely I can get the repo to work on local host, but in the IDE I get the following:

```
ReferenceError: /home/cabox/workspace/example/base.html:10
    8|   <body>
    9|     <div id="page"></div>
 >> 10|     <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.libBaseUrl 
%>/llsRecorder-v1.0.0.js"></script>
    11|   </body>
    12| </html>
    13| 

htmlWebpackPlugin is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous>     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:11:26)    
at returnedFn (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:555:17)
    at tryHandleCache     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:203:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
    at View.render     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
    at tryRender     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at EventEmitter.render     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /home/cabox/workspace/server.js:14:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]     (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I've installed the latest version of ejs with npm and setup my views as so (which works with local host):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/example');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render("base");
});
```

Any idea what could be going wrong between the local host on the IDE version? Something obvious such as 'public' being changed to the IDE folder name perhaps, or something equally small.

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: Where is `htmlWebpackPlugin` defined? On the server script?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way - there's a webpack.config.js file which is separate to server.js. The Github repo is here https://github.com/lingochamp/OnlineScorer-Web

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the variable to the render in the form of an object. The variable you're passing also has to exist in that same file either by `require`ing it or defining it there.(I don't exactly know how you're set up)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("base", {htmlWebpackPlugin: htmlWebpackPlugin});
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I've not really made many changes to the github repo at https://github.com/lingochamp/OnlineScorer-Web, which I imported into an IDE. To get it working with localhost I just did npm install, installed express globally and then added some paths to the relevant folders (and ejs as a views engine), and then run npm start. Doing this in the IDE hasn't worked - I've done npm install in the 'example' dir (no effect) + installed the htmlWebpackPlugin in the main node_modules dir (+ added your suggestion above) - neither change anything sadly. It seems strange that it works on localhost okay

Comment: p.s. the structure of the repo suggests htmlWebpackPlugin is defined in the  .../example/webpack.config.js file, and this appears to be referenced in the main package.json scripts:   "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -w"
  },